# getJSON not passing correct value to method in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, getjson

I spend almost whole day to find solution for this problem. I have no idea how to fix this.

This is my view:

```
<div id="Opis"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var idwyc = 2;
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Test","Pracownik_biurowy")',{ selectedWycieczka: idwyc } , function (data) {

            $('#Opis').append(data)
        });
    });
</script>
```

and method in Pracownik_biurowyController:

```
public ActionResult Test(int selectedWycieczka)
{

    var wycieczkaDetails =
       db.Wycieczka_fakultatywna.Where(w => w.Id_wycieczki == selectedWycieczka).Select(x => new
       {

           x.Opis,
           x.Koszt
       });

    return Json(wycieczkaDetails,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I think it should work but  I get all the time error.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'selectedWycieczka' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Test(Int32)' in
>   'BiuroPrototyp.Controllers.Pracownik_biurowyController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Nazwa parametru: parameters

RouteConfig:

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I just run your code, It didn't such an error.

Comment: Post your routing configuration. I'd bet that you need a route for it.

Comment: Ok, done. Post edited

Comment: Create a specific route, expecting your parameter for the Test method in your Pracownik_biurowyController.

Comment: Its weird because I have other methods in same controller but in different view. For example :` $.getJSON('/Pracownik_biurowy/GetPrzewodnicy', { id_regioniu: regid }, function (data) {...});` and it works fine..

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a JSON-object which can't be mapped to your routes because in the route you specify `{id}` but you are providing `selectedWycieczka`.

Change `{ selectedWycieczka: idwyc }` to `{ id: idwyc}` and in your controller change `public ActionResult Test(int selectedWycieczka)` to `public ActionResult Test(int id)`.

Why your other methods are working is unclear to me.

Comment: Still get a null. Maybe I should reinstall my VS or even Windows ?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I got it wrong again. Corrected answer once more. Reinstalling is really not necessary. It has nothing to do with VS or Windows.

Comment: I recognized that but its still not working. I try something like this:
`var target = '@Url.Action("Test", "Pracownik_biurowy")?id=' + idwyc;`
               `alert(target);`

and target have correct value like: `Pracownik_biurowy/Test?id=2`

But `alert(data)` its `undefined`.  Like I sad I have other methods like this and they works fine.

Comment: Where do you do `alert(data)`? Inside the getJSON callback?

Comment: Yes, but I moved whole script to different view in same Controller beacuse in previous(Test.csthml) I can't debug it.

Comment: I think this code it's fine. @Sirwan Afifi test it and it works. I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: If your alert shows `undefined` then the action has been called. The error must therefore be in your action code.

Comment: Ye, but even if I try return simple string in this method, data still `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm still don't know to fix this problem but I found how to work around this.
Maybe it is not good practice but it works. Im just taking id value from Request[] attribute

Method:

```
   public ActionResult GetWycieczkaDetails()
    {
        var id = Request["idWycieczka"];
        int selected = Int32.Parse(id);
        var wycieczkaDetails =
            db.Wycieczka_fakultatywna.Where(w => w.Id_wycieczki == selected).Select(x => new
            {
                x.Opis,
                x.Koszt
            });



        return Json(wycieczkaDetails.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Script:

```
    $('#SelectedWycieczka').change(function () { // <-- my dropdown
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();


    var target = '@Url.Action("GetWycieczkaDetails", "Home")?idWycieczka=' + id;
    $.getJSON(target,  function (data) {

        if (data.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#Opis').append(data[i].Opis);
                $('#Koszt').append(data[i].Koszt);
            }

        }
    });


});
```